# How do you bind an item to a quick button in Pokemon Black?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In previous generations, I could bind my bike to the <kbd>SELECT</kbd> button.  In Black 2, it doesn't seem to work.

**How do I bind an item to a quick button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not entirely true... You registered items via the Select button in GSC, RSE, FRLG but *not* in DPPt. It has been the <kbd>Y</kbd> button ever since the main Pokemon series games have been on DS...

On DPPt, it has been only one key item that you could register at a time accessible via the <kbd>Y</kbd> button.

On HGSS, you could assign up to two key items, one accessible via <kbd>Y</kbd> but both accessible via the touch screen.

On BW and BW2, you could assign multiple items (including specific menus) by checking a box. Items that can be registered have a checkable box to their left, and menus that can be registered have a checkable box at the bottom of the touch screen. Once they are registered, they can be accessed by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and then navigating the list of items/menus you registered

On XY (I know it's not entirely on topic, but just mentioning it), you can register up to 4 key items, accessible by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> on either the circle or D-pad.

---

Abbreviations used:

- GSC: Gold/Silver/Crystal
- RSE: Ruby/Sapphire/Emerald
- FRLG: FireRed/LeafGreen
- DPPt: Diamond/Pearl/Platinum
- HGSS: HeartGold/SoulSilver
- BW: Black/White
- BW2: Black 2/White 2

Answer (score 1):

From the items menu, register the item, and then use the <kbd>Y</kbd> button in game to use the item.